# Put endpoint returns a 400 in postman and 500 in browser

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following endpoint:

```
@PutMapping("/{projectIdentifiers}/analysts/{analystEmail}")
public void assignProjectsToAnalyst(@PathVariable List<String> projectIdentifiers, @PathVariable String analystEmail) {
    projectService.assignProjectsToAnalyst(projectIdentifiers, analystEmail.toLowerCase());
}
```

I have a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice which takes care of handling exceptions.

```
@ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
@ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
public ExceptionDTO handleBadRequestException(BadRequestException exception) {
    return new ExceptionDTO(exception.getMessage());
}
```

If I throw an exception, I should get a 400 with the following error message:

{
"errorMessage": "Some error"
}

While testing from Postman and Swagger page, it works as expected, while testing from the react application which calls this endpoint, the network tab in the developer tools in Chrome is showing the backend is responding with a 500.

This doesn't seems to make any sense.

Could it be the fact the the method does not return anything in the endpoint definition?

The class is annotated with @RestController

Comment: A `500` response usually is delegated to the server, which will respond like that if something failed and couldn't be recovered (with a RESTful framework, it's not usual that you manually respond a `500`). Because of that, I think that there must be a difference between the request made by Postman and the one made by the browser, and the latter makes the server fail.

Comment: You might be getting exception stacktrace in console for 500 internal error. Can you please provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not posted your react code, and the error you're getting from your browser. I recommend a way to debug if there is any difference between your browser request and postman request.

1. In your chrome browser, right click on your request in network tab and then choose "Copy as cURL(bash)"
2. In your postman, choose the code tab in the right panel (the little "</>" icon), then select cURL in dropdown.

Now you can compare 2 cURL requests. As you said that it works in postman as expected, then there is likely an issue in your browser code :)